# Installing necessary packages to use libbfd (Binary File Descriptor) library

Tags: software-installation, libraries

I am trying to set up my development environment in a Ubuntu 20.04 image running in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). I want to be able to use the package for Binary File Descriptor (`libbfd`) as described in the book Practical Binary Analysis, written by Dennis Andriesse, and published by No Starch Press.

He provides a Ubuntu VM which I've downloaded, but I want to replicate what he's done by using that library in my own Ubuntu WSL image. Unfortunately the book and associated website do not have instructions for how he set up the VM.

Long story short: I would like to install the `libbfd` library which I thought was part of binary-utils. I installed the binary-essentials package but still do not see the library.

Has anyone been able to find where I can install that library from?

Thanks!

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/binutils-dev/filelist

Comment: Thanks so much! I installed `binutils-dev` and got it.

Answer (score 4):

The answer was posted as a comment to my original post. Basically, installing the `binutils-dev` package resolved my problem.